# Assigning Values to Specific Rows and Columns of Numpy Array at the Same Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

My Expected Output for Code below:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  999,  999,  7],
       [ 8,  999, 999, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(range(16)).reshape((4,4))
A[[1,3],:][:, [1,3]] = [[999,999],[999,999]]
print(A)
```

However, the values are unchanged. The output is

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

What should I do to get the desired output?
I am not allowed to use loops to assign each value manually.

**Update:**
**Scenario 2**: if I want A[[1,3], [1,3]] = inner, it throws an exception shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,). What should I do?

desired output for scenario 2:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
      [ 4,  999,  6,  999],
      [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
      [12, 999, 14, 999]])
```

Comment: In `A[[1,3],:][:, [1,3]]=`  `A[[1,3],:]` is a `copy` not a `view`.  You can't use sequential indexing during an assignment.  Combine the row and column indices in a way that `broadcasts` to the desired block: `A[[[1],[3]], [1,3]]=...`  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Specific Solution

You can do the following to get the desired outcome:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array(range(16)).reshape((4,4))

inner = np.array([[999,999],[999,999]])

border = 1
A[border:border + inner.shape[0],
    border:border + inner.shape[1]] = inner
```

- The inner array is defined separately for clarity.
- The point of `border` is to define how far away from the border you are.
- The output of `A` is:

```
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4, 999, 999,   7],
       [  8, 999, 999,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15]])
```

#### Generalized 2-Dimensional Solution

In the example above, it happens to be case that the inner-array is the same distance in both directions of the outer-array but you can define and adjust two `border` parameters to generalize the solution. For example, if the original array was larger (10x10) and you wanted to imbed a (3x3) array in side of it in an arbitrary location, you can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array(range(100)).reshape((10,10))

inner = np.array([[999,999,999],[999,999,999],[999,999,999]])

border_1 = 1
border_2 = 4
A[border_1:border_1 + inner.shape[0],
    border_2:border_2 + inner.shape[1]] = inner
```

The output of A is:

```
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12,  13, 999, 999, 999,  17,  18,  19],
       [ 20,  21,  22,  23, 999, 999, 999,  27,  28,  29],
       [ 30,  31,  32,  33, 999, 999, 999,  37,  38,  39],
       [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49],
       [ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59],
       [ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69],
       [ 70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79],
       [ 80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89],
       [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99]])
```

#### Extra Tip

Instead of manually writing the array of 999's, you can take advantage of `np.full`.

```
np.full((3, 3), 999)
```

produces...

```
array([[999, 999, 999],
       [999, 999, 999],
       [999, 999, 999]])
```

This could make writing the inner array much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, if I want `A[[1,3], [1,3]] = inner`, it throws an exception `shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)`. What should I do?

Comment: You'll need to write it like `A[1:3, 1:3] = inner`. `A[[1, 3]]` for example will grab the 2nd and 4th rows, then if you do `A[[1, 3], [1, 3]]`, it will give you the 2nd and 4th elements of the 2nd and 4th rows. This leaves you with `A[[1, 3], [1, 3]] = array([999,  15])` which is not what you're wanting. Hope this helps.

Comment: For scenario 2, I indeed would like to get the 2nd and 4th elements of the 2nd and 4th rows. However, shouldn't A[[1, 3], [1, 3]] return a ndarray of 4 elements instead of 2?

Comment: Of course! FYI the official [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) for indexing is quite helpful for learning.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to demonstrate how to index blocks of an array.

```
In [52]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4);arr
Out[52]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Indexing with 2 lists (that are the same size), selects a "diagonal":

```
In [53]: arr[[1,3],[1,3]]
Out[53]: array([ 5, 15])
```

In effect that is selecting `arr[1,1]` and `arr[3,3]`, pairing up one values from each list.  You can't assign a (2,2) block to that (2,) shape.

You selected a block with a double indexing:

```
In [54]: arr[[1,3],:][:,[1,3]]
Out[54]: 
array([[ 5,  7],
       [13, 15]])
```

That works for fetching, but not for assignment.  The first indexing returns a copy, so an further attempt to assign a value will modify that copy, not the original array.

In the comment I suggested indexing with two lists:

```
In [55]: arr[[[1],[3]],[1,3]]
Out[55]: 
array([[ 5,  7],
       [13, 15]])
```

More generally we use a helper function to convert two 1d lists into arrays that `broadcast` against each other:

```
In [56]: np.ix_([1,3],[1,3])
Out[56]: 
(array([[1],
        [3]]),
 array([[1, 3]]))
```

That tuple of arrays can select our block, and can be used for setting:

```
In [57]: arr[_]
Out[57]: 
array([[ 5,  7],
       [13, 15]])
```

You may want to review the concept of `broadcasting`.  It's as important when indexing as it is when doing math.  The same rules apply, for example to add the two arrays in [56]:

```
In [58]: Out[56][0]+Out[56][1]
Out[58]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [4, 6]])
```

For this pair of indexing lists, we could use slices to select the same block:

```
In [59]: arr[1::2, 1::2]
Out[59]: 
array([[ 5,  7],
       [13, 15]])
```

[59] is an example `basic` indexing, while all the others are `advanced` indexing.  I've given an important link to the indexing documentation.

Finally to demonstrate the assignment:

```
In [60]: arr[[[1],[3]],[1,3]] = [[100,110],[120,130]]
In [61]: arr
Out[61]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4, 100,   6, 110],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12, 120,  14, 130]])

In [62]: arr[1::2, 1::2] = -1
In [63]: arr
Out[63]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, -1,  6, -1],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, -1, 14, -1]])
```